# Function out param that shouldn't be modified C++

Tags: c++, pointers, parameter-passing

I want to return an array back to the caller. To avoid copying the array, I want to return by reference. I want to ensure that the caller only uses it without modifying it.

For example -

```
class A {
  int func1(char **outparam);
  char property[20];
};

main() {
  char *prop;
  int err = func1(&prop);
  if (!err) {
     cout << prop << endl;
     prop[2] = 'c';       // Shouldn't allow this
  }
}
```

How can I ensure that prop is not modified.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Use pass-by-reference instead of pointers.  And in your code `func1` is a member of class `A`, but main calls it like a free function.. It would be better if you posted actual code that you compiled

Comment: `const char **outparam`

Comment: @M.M How would I return an out param through pass-by-reference?

Comment: @melpomene would marking the out param as const char ** in the function declaration make it const in the caller's context too?

Comment: I would suggest not using an array at all. Instead use a class that hides the functionality which you want the caller to not have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the result to a pointer to const and use this instead.

```
int func1(char ** outparam);

int main()
{
  char * prop;
  int err = func1(&prop);
  const char * outprop = prop; // outprop points to same data but is const
  if (!err) {
    std::cout << outprop << std::endl;
    outprop[2] = 'c'; // error: read-only variable is not assignable
  }
}
```

On the other hand I think your design is flawed but it is not so easy to say without knowing more context.  Probably more like this:

```
std::string func1();

int main()
{
  try
  {
    std::string const prop = func1();
    std::cout << prop << std::endl;
  }
  catch (std::exception const& e)
  {
    // Error handling ...
  }
}
```